# R plotting boxplot with different amount of entries

Tags: matrix, boxplot

I have a matrix that is 50x2.  But column 2 has different amount of entries.  How can I make a box plot where the x axis is position and the y axis are the different counts?  Ideally, I'd like to take the absolute value of the counts.  Thanks in advance!

```
> mat.count[1:50,]
    position               count
1  136873135                   0
2  136873136                   0
3  136873137                   0
4  136873138                   0
5  136873139                   0
6  136873140                 -15
7  136873141                   0
8  136873142                   0
9  136873143                   0
10 136873144                   0
11 136873145                   0
12 136873146                   0
13 136873147                   0
14 136873148                   0
15 136873149                   0
16 136873150                   0
17 136873151                   0
18 136873152                   0
19 136873153                   0
20 136873154                   0
21 136873155                   0
22 136873156                   0
23 136873157                   0
24 136873158                   0
25 136873159                   0
26 136873160                   0
27 136873161                   0
28 136873162                   0
29 136873163                   0
30 136873164                   0
31 136873165                   0
32 136873166                   0
33 136873167                   0
34 136873168                  -1
35 136873169                   0
36 136873170                   0
37 136873171                   0
38 136873172                   0
39 136873173                 -70
40 136873174                 -66
41 136873175 -73,-1,-1,-1,-73,-1
42 136873176                 -52
43 136873177                   0
44 136873178                   0
45 136873179              -66,-1
46 136873180                  -1
47 136873181                   0
48 136873182             -68,-75
49 136873183             -67,-67
50 136873184         -60,-56,-56
```